# C# implicit operator for class with generic type to other generic type

Tags: c#, generics, operator-keyword

I got a C# class with a generic type. I'd like to have an implicit operator which converts an instance of this class to an instance of the same class with another generic type parameter.

```cs
class MyClass<T>
{
    public static implicit operator MyClass<TOther>(MyClass<T> self)
    {
        /* conversion */
    }
}
```

However the C# compiler says "The type or namespace name 'TOther' could not be found".

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Your requirement seems strange to me. What you're actually saying is that you want an implicit conversion between T and TOther while they are being used as type parameters in `MyClass`. Even if the compiler would allow that, Consider an implicit conversion between `MyClass<byte>` and `MyClass<DateTime>` - how would you write this conversion? Is it even possible?

Comment: This has been discussed: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/612 But I don't think this is worth to implement, because you can definitely add a `ConvertTo<U>` method to achieve it.

Comment: Definitly not via an implict cast, which states **there's no loss of data when converting from one type to the other**. E.g. you can easily convert an `int` to a `float`, but not the other way round (you'd need an *explicit* cast to do that). But even with an explicit cast, you can't do what you want, unless `MyClass` was co- or contra-variant and `T` and `TOther` have some inheritance-relation.

Comment: I appreciate your comments but I do not require assistance with the requirement or the conversion itself. This is solely about how to declare the operator.

Comment: The point is: your requirement makes no sense, as Zolar pointed out. So there's no support for that. So simply the answer to your question is: no, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to use a generic type parameter (TOther) that is not defined in the scope of your class (MyClass). The compiler cannot infer what type TOther is supposed to be, and therefore gives you an error.

To achieve your goal, you need to define the generic type parameter TOther either at the class level or at the method level. For example, you can do:

```
// Define TOther at the class level
class MyClass<T, TOther>
{
    public static implicit operator MyClass<TOther, T>(MyClass<T, TOther> self)
    {
        // conversion
    }
}
```

Comment: defining `TOther` on class-level for the sake of a single operator? Definitly no good idea. Imagine you had multiple such conversions. Would you really want to add a generic argument for every target-type?